# 500 Error on Experience Editor - Security

Tags: experience-editor, security

I'm getting a  System.ArgumentNullException while in Preview or Experience Editor.

I have since pointed a blank instance of Sitecore  (8.1 update 3) to the dbs and can replicate the issue but cannot find the root cause:

[image: Stack Trace]

From the trace it would appear that the issue is access related - the item cannot be read by the current user. However, I cannot identify any items that have security on them for the user (admin).

I have run the SPE report to find items with security on for the user but this yields no results.

Are there any other areas I can investigate here? Please ask if you require additional information, I am fairly new to Sitecore.

Comment: It is the item which is null and not the security. Please check on the edit mode if there is any invalid item or you can check from the Presentation details if there are any missing renderings.

Comment: `ItemPath` class does a `ItemManager.GetRootItem(Language.Invariant, Version.First, currentItem.Database, SecurityCheck.Disable)` call which then fires `getRootItem` pipeline to get root item of you database (and that root item is null). You should be able to add a new processor to the `getRootItem` pipeline to see what is the database, language and version and why this is doesn't work. Btw there are no processors in that pipeline by default and standard `ItemProvider` is used instead.

Comment: Thanks both - will investigate adding a new processor to the pipeline and let you know how i get on. @HishaamNamooya it is occurring on every page so unlikely to be missing renderings I suppose.

Comment: @James, so it is based only on the item. There might be an item on the page that is present on every page which is causing this issue. The error `ArgumentNotNull` is when Sitecore is performing unit testing on the item.

Comment: Reinstalled root items to resolve it. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In the end - I reinstalled the sitecore and sitecore/content items (preserving the subtree) from a clean install and this resolved the issue. The CMS was unable to access the database's root item.